# How to add my newly created Ec2 filesystem to /etc/fstab so that it get mounted automatically on next boot

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that created on Amazon aws server, with a volume of 8G, and later created another volume of 800G so i could attach to my previous 8G volume. I then created a new filesystem and mounted the 800G volume on /opt/mountpoint directory
by using this command

Assuming the new volume is /dev/xvdb:

```
$ mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
$ mkdir /opt/mountpoint
$ mount /dev/xvdb /opt/mountpoint
```

At this point, my storage is available at /opt/mountpoint.  I need to know how to add this new filesystem to /etc/fstab so that it gets mounted automatically on next boot ?

Comment: @Madhatter, after adding -1, at least you could give a suggestion !

Comment: 1) You don't know it was me who downvoted.  2) If you mouseover the "down" arrow, you'll see the text "This questions does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.", and downvotes without comment may be assumed to be for that reason.  My suggestion is: do some research.  `man fstab` would probably be a good start.

Comment: @Madhatter, Really i see nothing unclear about this question, this question contains the complete step of mounting a new volume after attached, except for the last step "adding it to /etc/fstab/ " which could be of great help to other users. if i haven't made any research...how do u think i even got to this point?

Comment: @Madhatter, thks anyway, man fstab was actually a good start! i made my research & got my answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it fixed & this is how i did it
After attaching the volume & running this

```
$ mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
$ mkdir /opt/mountpoint 
$ mount /dev/xvdb /opt/mountpoint
```

you'll probably get an error when you run the third command "mount /dev/xvdb /opt/mountpoint", so i read this [sshing-into-ec2-server-via-gives-error-please-login-as-the-ec2-user-user-rather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230516/sshing-into-ec2-server-via-gives-error-please-login-as-the-ec2-user-user-rather)

```
$ sudo su
```

to become the root user.

And then read this furthermore [Mounting an attached ebs volume in EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/114944/mounting-an-attached-ebs-volume-in-ec2?rq=1) using

```
$ echo "/dev/xvdb  /opt/mountpoint  ext4     noatime  0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

this adds my new filesystem to /etc/fstab

```
$df -h
```

using df -h to view my file system mounted on the EBS volume after reboot